# How to use AST to make specific statements commented out in Python?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a Python script but I don't want to change it.
I want to use another script to modify the original one and call to run the original one with all the "print" or "time.sleep" statements being commentted out(not run).
I search for it and find a method using AST, but I really don't have a idea of how to use it.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to manipulate the AST to achieve that, but it would probably be easier to monkeypatch whatever objects it uses prior to running. In your specific example, to incapacitate `print` and `time.sleep`, you could do this:

```
def insomniac(duration):
    pass  # don't sleep

_original_sleep = time.sleep
time.sleep = insomniac

def dont_write(stuff):
    pass  # don't write

_original_write = sys.stdout.write
sys.stdout.write = dont_write
```

To get the functionality back, you can set the relevant functions back to the stored originals. If you want to be truer to your original intention such that calls to these functions from the script in question are nullified but calls from other modules still work, you can inspect the stack to see what module the caller is in and selectively call the original or ignore the call.

Comment: sorry,can you explain it to me in detail?
How can I write these codes?

Comment: does it look like:import test
import subprocess
import ast
import os
import time
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":

    def insomniac(duration):
        pass  # don't sleep

    _original_sleep = time.sleep
    time.sleep = insomniac

    def dont_write(stuff):
        pass  # don't write

    _original_write = sys.stdout.write
    sys.stdout.write = dont_write

    os.system("test.py")
    exit(0)

Comment: @user3327884: No, `os.system` will run a separate Python process where the changes will not be carried over. You'd want to use [`execfile`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#execfile).

Comment: but now the script can't run exectly...
import test
import subprocess
import ast
import os
import time
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":

    def insomniac(duration):
        pass  # don't sleep

    _original_sleep = time.sleep
    time.sleep = insomniac

    def dont_write(stuff):
        pass  # don't write

    _original_write = sys.stdout.write
    sys.stdout.write = dont_write

    execfile("test.py")

    exit(0)

Comment: @user3327884: If it doesn't run, what *does* it do? It's hard to debug something without knowing what's wrong.